# Please Explain: SassScript parent-selector property

Tags: html, css, sass, less, stylus

I have saw this code in sassscript but it does'nt make my sense and I'm unable to found any official documentation regarding the mention sasscript css output

SassScript

```
.main aside:hover,
.sidebar p {
  parent-selector: &;
  // => ((unquote(".main") unquote("aside:hover")),
  //     (unquote(".sidebar") unquote("p")))
}
```

CSS Output

```
.main aside:hover,
.sidebar p {
  parent-selector: .main aside:hover, .sidebar p;
}
```

explain how this will work, in css. is this officially documented by w3c or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can see the CSS output. now tell me how this css apply to html element. becuase parent-selector is property .main aside:hover is value. i want css in action of above mentioned code here is the link 
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/

Comment: Well pointed out, indeed, currently it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

In standard CSS, there is no "`parent-selector`" functionality. CSS primarily deals with selecting and styling elements based on their relationship to other elements, but it doesn't provide a way to select a parent based on the behavior of its children.

So, this won't work:

```
.main aside:hover,
.sidebar p {
  parent-selector: .main aside:hover, .sidebar p;
}
```

Well pointed out, indeed, currently it is useless.

In the CSS Selectors Level 4 Working Draft introduced a new pseudo-class called `:has()`, which allows us to select parent - which is currently not supported in all major browsers.

```
li:has(> a.active) {
  /* styles to apply to the li tag */
}
```

In this example, it selects the `li` element that is a direct parent of the `a` element with class `active`.

Comment: A parent selector is implemented in newer browsers but is not fully adopted. [Is there a css parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: SassScript Preprocessor generating CSS code. if the metioned code generated by SassScript then what its application to document this. @Paulie_D this is another case. because SassScript generating parent-selector as css property. which is useless, i guess.

Comment: Yes, at the time we are discussing this it is "useless". I've updated my answer.

Comment: The above sass script code using the Ampersand which uses to adding prefix of parent selector, they are just for the demonstration purpose what happens when we add ampersand as a value.

Comment: The ampersand (`&`) is commonly used in CSS preprocessors like SASS (Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets) and SCSS (Sassy CSS) to reference the parent selector in nested rules.  This feature allows you to write more concise and maintainable CSS code, particularly when dealing with complex selector combinations. In SASS or SCSS, you can use the ampersand to concatenate selectors and create more specific rules. Here's a basic example: `.button {background-color: blue;&:hover {background-color: red;}}` which is compiled to:`.button {background-color: blue;}.button:hover {background-color: red;}`